# Given ISO and timezone strings, how to convert them to UTC string in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-conversion

For example, I have an ISO string "2022-12-22T18:20:00.000", and a timezone string "US/Eastern". How do I convert them into a UTC time in the same format (iso 8601), using Java?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-22T18:20:00.000").atZone(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern")).toInstant()`

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov This suits my needs well. thanks!

Comment: Did you search? Please do. Similar questions have been asked and answered over and over. I believe you would get a good answer faster that way.

Comment: US/Eastern is a deprecated time zone ID. It works, but prefer America/New_York (which is what you get anyway). Time zone IDs are in *region/city* format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** **Update** **

A better version, thanks to Arvind's response below.

```java
    final ZonedDateTime americaNewYork =
            LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-22T18:20:00.000")
                         .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
    final Instant utc = americaNewYork.toInstant();
```

---

**First Pass**

I'm not at a computer where I can test this but I think this might do the trick...

```java
    final ZonedDateTime usEastern =
            LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-22T18:20:00.000", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
                         .atZone(ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
    final ZonedDateTime utc = usEastern.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked :) The output converted to string in this case would be "2022-12-22T23:20Z[UTC]". Using @AndreyB.Panfilov 's answer we can get a string without the timezone "2022-12-22T23:20:00Z".

Comment: Good Answer, but I would make that second line an `OffsetDateTime` as there is no time zone, only an offset.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74806822/10819573) is correct but there are a few things that are important for future visitors to this page.

### You do not need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter`

`java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need to specify a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `2015-03-21T11:08:14.859831`).

### Get an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) out of the `ZonedDateTime`

Once you convert the `LocalDateTime`, parsed from the given date-time string, into a `ZonedDateTime`, I recommend you get an `Instant` out of this `ZonedDateTime`. An `Instant` is an instantaneous point on the timeline, and normally this is represented using a UTC timescale.

### *US/Eastern* is deprecated

As you find at [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), *US/Eastern* is deprecated. I recommend you avoid using *US/Eastern* and use *America/New_York* instead.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.List;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        ZonedDateTime zdt = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-22T18:20:00.000")
                                         .atZone(zone);
        // Alternatively
        // zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-22T18:20:00.000"), zone);

        Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2022-12-22T23:20:00Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wnrEqa)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.